# Gridview update fails without error message. Accessdatasource in Visual Web Developer

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I have a problem that I have been trying to tackle for the last 24 hours so to avoid me going insane I thought I'd ask someone for help with my problem!

I am using Visual Web Developer, and in this I have an asp Gridview element which selects information from my AccessDataSource. (Which I might add works perfectly fine.)

My error comes when I try to update the information in the Gridview. My update SQL works fine in Access, however in VWD it throws no error message but fails to save the new data to the database. I have set the parameters in asp for the update command, and I have the 'DataKeyNames' set, too.

Can anyone help me with this? I am relatively new to this and I just can't see where I am going wrong. I have been doing extensive searching online for a good while and still couldn't quite see it, so I thought my next best shot was to ask on here.

Many thanks in advance. :)

My ASP.net code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataKeyNames="MemberID" 
style="z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: 147px; position: absolute; height: 133px;     
width:499px">
<Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="RaceID" HeaderText="RaceID" SortExpression="RaceID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="MemberID" HeaderText="MemberID" SortExpression="MemberID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="MemberName" HeaderText="MemberName"   
SortExpression="MemberName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="PersonalTime" HeaderText="PersonalTime" 
SortExpression="PersonalTime" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FinishPosition" HeaderText="FinishPosition" 
SortExpression="FinishPosition" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Points" HeaderText="Points" 
SortExpression="Points" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server"     
DataFile="~/App_Data/myDatabase.mdb" 

SelectCommand="SELECT tblResult.RaceID, tblResult.MemberID, tblMember.MemberName, 
tblResult.PersonalTime, tblResult.FinishPosition, tblPoint.Points FROM ((tblRaceType  
INNER JOIN (tblRace INNER JOIN (tblMember INNER JOIN tblResult ON tblMember.MemberID = 
tblResult.MemberID) ON tblRace.RaceID = tblResult.RaceID) ON tblRaceType.RaceTypeID = 
tblRace.RaceTypeID) INNER JOIN tblPoint ON tblResult.FinishPosition = tblPoint.
[Position] AND tblRaceType.RaceTypeID = tblPoint.RaceTypeID) WHERE (tblResult.RaceID =    
?) AND (tblPoint.RaceTypeID = ?) ORDER BY tblResult.FinishPosition" 

UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblResult] SET PersonalTime = ?, FinishPosition = ? WHERE  
MemberID = ? AND RaceID = ?">

<SelectParameters>
<asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="?" SessionField="raceID" />
<asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="?" SessionField="raceTypeID" />
</SelectParameters>

<UpdateParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="PersonalTime" Type="String"/>
<asp:Parameter Name="FinishPosition" Type="Int64" />
<asp:Parameter Name="MemberID" Type="Int64" />
<asp:Parameter Name="RaceID" Type="Int64" />
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same problem:

I had to just wrap my already existing VB code in "If Not Page.IsPostBack". Think this was interfering with the Update by re-loading the page and before it got to execute the Update command.

Answer (score 0):

This link on stackoverflow has a similar situation. I'm not sure about the environment, but it may not be a Visual Web Developer issue.. Either way here is the link:

[Update of AccessDatasource does nothing but has no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779086/update-of-accessdatasource-does-nothing-but-has-no-error)

It didn't look like that issue was resolved but there were some tips on there that might help.

-doddy

(I'm also having the same problem so if you end up with a good solution please do post it!! Thanks!)

Comment: The problem has been solved! There were no errors in the code, however on my page load I did not have If Not Page.IsPostback. Once this was in, it worked. :)

Comment: Did you have to enable view state on your page load?

Comment: I didn't, I had to just wrap my already existing code in

 "If Not Page.IsPostBack" 

Think this was interfering with the Update by re-loading the page and before it got to execute the Update command.

Comment: Makes sense. That's what it looks like for me too.. Almost like the page loads SelectCommand on postback which causes the data to be identical.. Thanks!

Comment: Made the change then had a different error: "You have specified that your update command compares all values on SqlDataSource 'AccessDataSource1', but the dictionary passed in for oldValues is empty."  I just changed my ConflictDetection statement from ="CompareAllValues" to ="OverwriteChanges" and it worked for me.